# Google App Engine to Amazon Web Services Beanstalk: App.yaml Equivalent

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently migrating my PHP app from Google App Engine to Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk. I can't figure out how to redirect clean URLs the way GAE does through its app.yaml file under handlers on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

I have looked countless times on AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP documentation for instructions or examples regarding a similar process, but I can't find anything. I would appreciate it if someone could provide an example or direct toward the appropriate documentation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "redirect clean URLs"? I think anything like this will involve modifying your Beanstalk server's Apache config. I would search for how to accomplish the redirect rules you desire in Apache, and then search for how to customize the Apache config in Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll be sure to look into the Apache Config for Elastic Beanstalk.